# Why do we bother about commuting limit and integral in the theory of Lebesgue integraion?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, intuition

Consider the following paragraph from [this article](https://www.math3ma.com/blog/fatous-lemma) on Fatou's Lemma

> Fatou's Lemma, the Monotone Convergence Theorem (MCT), and the
> Dominated Convergence Theorem (DCT) are three major results in the
> theory of Lebesgue integration which answer the question **"When do
> $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ and $\int$ commute?**" The MCT and DCT
> tell us that if you place certain restrictions on both the $f_n$ and
> $f$, then you can interchange the limit and integral. On the other
> hand, Fatou's Lemma says, "Here's the best you can do if you don't put
> any restrictions on the functions."

I recently started measure theory and hence I am not in a position to visualize or intuitively understand everything.

In this context, I want to know about the importance of the question I bolded above. Is there any easy explanation for understanding the **necessity** of commuting the both?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3627790/why-dominated-convergence-theorem-is-related-to-the-superiority-of-lebesgue-inte

Comment: Concerning the question in the title: because we are eager to know when it is justified to conclude (from pointwise convergence of $f_n$ to $f$) that $\int f_n$ converges to $\int f$.

Comment: Simply put, it is useful to know when $\int f_n \to \int f$ because we might know stuff about $f$ and want to say stuff about $\lim \int f_n$.

Comment: @Doiglas: Or maybe we know stuff about $f_n$ and want to know something about $\int f$.